# Limit field permissions on Graphene Django

Tags: python, django, graphene-django

Lets say I got a user Type

```
class UserType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            "fieldA",
            "fieldB",
            "relationshipA",
            "relationshipB"
        ]
```

And I want `fieldB` and `relationshipB` to be visible only to the owner (user).
What is the best strategy to do this?
Initially Ive created a `PublicUserType` excluding private fields, but quickly I realized that it might not be scalable because not only I'll have to create private representation for `UserType` I'll might also create private representation for any relationship (`relationshipA`  etc), and proper resolvers, and duplicate fragments etc.
Is there a best practice here?

Comment: Take a look at this example: https://docs.graphene-python.org/projects/django/en/latest/queries/#default-queryset

Comment: But how can it help with hiding specific fields?

Comment: You can filter in the `queryset` or using a field resolver (for example: `resolve_fieldB(self, info)` to return `None` if `fieldB` must be hidden. Keep in mind that different from APIs, you will need a GQL query specifing the fields you want to query. If you have sure that a public user will not query the "private" fields, You can raise an `GraphQLError("Entity not found")`.

Comment: I think that overriding resolvers might be better suited for my needs, thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to limit field access on a model based on user type on Graphene/Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49084322/how-to-limit-field-access-on-a-model-based-on-user-type-on-graphene-django)

Comment: Yes, that's pretty close to what we discussed above, thanks @Ahtisham, I will also create permissions decorator to prevent boilerplate code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is:
Create `decorators.py` file

```
from functools import wraps
from graphql import GraphQLError
from api.utils import snake_to_camel_case

def private_field(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(self, info):
        user = info.context.user

        if user.id != self.id:
            field_name = func.__name__.replace('resolve_', '')
            field_name_camel_cased = snake_to_camel_case(field_name)
            raise GraphQLError(f'You do not have permissions to access {field_name}')
        
        return func(self, info)
    return wrapper
```

snake_to_camel_case func:

```
def snake_to_camel_case(string):
    components = string.split('_')
    return components[0] + ''.join(x.title() for x in components[1:])
```

and finally on my schema file resolver:

```
@private_field
    def resolve_private_field(self, info):
        return self.private_field
```

Response should look something like that:

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "message": "You do not have permissions to access privateField",
...
```

Now obviously this solution is super specific for my needs atm but it should be easy enough to make it more generic and scalable for any scenario.