# Encountring Error While installing django dependency "Building wheel for xmlsec (pyproject.toml) ... error error: subprocess-exited-with-error"

Tags: python, django

I am using this command to install dependencies for django project
pip install -r requirements.txt

` Installing build dependencies ... done
Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
Installing backend dependencies ... done
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting yarl==1.7.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 369))
Using cached yarl-1.7.2-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (121 kB)
Collecting zipp==3.1.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 371))
Using cached zipp-3.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (4.9 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=3.0 in ./kit/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from gunicorn==20.1.0->-r requirements.txt (line 154)) (56.0.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: xmlsec, django-rest-hooks
Building wheel for xmlsec (pyproject.toml) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Building wheel for xmlsec (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [65 lines of output]
running bdist_wheel
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-38
creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-38/xmlsec
copying src/xmlsec/py.typed -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-38/xmlsec
copying src/xmlsec/tree.pyi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-38/xmlsec
copying src/xmlsec/**init**.pyi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-38/xmlsec
copying src/xmlsec/constants.pyi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-38/xmlsec
copying src/xmlsec/template.pyi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-38/xmlsec
running build_ext
building 'xmlsec' extension
creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-38
creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-38/private
creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-38/private/var
creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-38/private/var/folders
creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-38/private/var/folders/0f
creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-38/private/var/folders/0f/pwhvtlxn26j0cfry2wrpvb7r0000gn
creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-38/private/var/folders/0f/pwhvtlxn26j0cfry2wrpvb7r0000gn/T
creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-38/private/var/folders/0f/pwhvtlxn26j0cfry2wrpvb7r0000gn/T/pip-install-y3izz7rd
creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-38/private/var/folders/0f/pwhvtlxn26j0cfry2wrpvb7r0000gn/T/pip-install-y3izz7rd/xmlsec_1b2a1e6a17e447509a7b6137df7d3b99
creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-38/private/var/folders/0f/pwhvtlxn26j0cfry2wrpvb7r0000gn/T/pip-install-y3izz7rd/xmlsec_1b2a1e6a17e447509a7b6137df7d3b99/src
gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -D__XMLSEC_FUNCTION__=**func** -DXMLSEC_NO_FTP=1 -DXMLSEC_NO_MD5=1 -DXMLSEC_NO_GOST=1 -DXMLSEC_NO_GOST2012=1 -DXMLSEC_NO_CRYPTO_DYNAMIC_LOADING=1 -DXMLSEC_CRYPTO_OPENSSL=1 -DMODULE_NAME=xmlsec -DMODULE_VERSION=1.3.12 -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libxmlsec1/1.3.1_1/include/xmlsec1 -I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/include/openssl -I/private/var/folders/0f/pwhvtlxn26j0cfry2wrpvb7r0000gn/T/pip-build-env-5ws1iwun/normal/lib/python3.8/site-packages/lxml/includes -I/private/var/folders/0f/pwhvtlxn26j0cfry2wrpvb7r0000gn/T/pip-build-env-5ws1iwun/normal/lib/python3.8/site-packages/lxml -I/private/var/folders/0f/pwhvtlxn26j0cfry2wrpvb7r0000gn/T/pip-build-env-5ws1iwun/normal/lib/python3.8/site-packages/lxml/includes/**pycache** -I/Users/nehanegi/Downloads/analytickit-first/kit/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -c /private/var/folders/0f/pwhvtlxn26j0cfry2wrpvb7r0000gn/T/pip-install-y3izz7rd/xmlsec_1b2a1e6a17e447509a7b6137df7d3b99/src/constants.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-cpython-38/private/var/folders/0f/pwhvtlxn26j0cfry2wrpvb7r0000gn/T/pip-install-y3izz7rd/xmlsec_1b2a1e6a17e447509a7b6137df7d3b99/src/constants.o -g -std=c99 -fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing -Wno-error=declaration-after-statement -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Os
/private/var/folders/0f/pwhvtlxn26j0cfry2wrpvb7r0000gn/T/pip-install-y3izz7rd/xmlsec_1b2a1e6a17e447509a7b6137df7d3b99/src/constants.c:319:5: error: use of undeclared identifier 'xmlSecSoap11Ns'
PYXMLSEC_ADD_NS_CONSTANT(Soap11Ns, "SOAP11");
^
/private/var/folders/0f/pwhvtlxn26j0cfry2wrpvb7r0000gn/T/pip-install-y3izz7rd/xmlsec_1b2a1e6a17e447509a7b6137df7d3b99/src/constants.c:304:46: note: expanded from macro 'PYXMLSEC_ADD_NS_CONSTANT'
tmp = PyUnicode_FromString((const char*)(JOIN(xmlSec, name))); 
^
/private/var/folders/0f/pwhvtlxn26j0cfry2wrpvb7r0000gn/T/pip-install-y3izz7rd/xmlsec_1b2a1e6a17e447509a7b6137df7d3b99/src/common.h:19:19: note: expanded from macro 'JOIN'
#define JOIN(X,Y) DO_JOIN1(X,Y)
^
/private/var/folders/0f/pwhvtlxn26j0cfry2wrpvb7r0000gn/T/pip-install-y3izz7rd/xmlsec_1b2a1e6a17e447509a7b6137df7d3b99/src/common.h:20:23: note: expanded from macro 'DO_JOIN1'
#define DO_JOIN1(X,Y) DO_JOIN2(X,Y)
^
/private/var/folders/0f/pwhvtlxn26j0cfry2wrpvb7r0000gn/T/pip-install-y3izz7rd/xmlsec_1b2a1e6a17e447509a7b6137df7d3b99/src/common.h:21:23: note: expanded from macro 'DO_JOIN2'
#define DO_JOIN2(X,Y) X##Y
^
:81:1: note: expanded from here
xmlSecSoap11Ns
^
/private/var/folders/0f/pwhvtlxn26j0cfry2wrpvb7r0000gn/T/pip-install-y3izz7rd/xmlsec_1b2a1e6a17e447509a7b6137df7d3b99/src/constants.c:320:5: error: use of undeclared identifier 'xmlSecSoap12Ns'; did you mean 'xmlSecXPath2Ns'?
PYXMLSEC_ADD_NS_CONSTANT(Soap12Ns, "SOAP12");
^
/private/var/folders/0f/pwhvtlxn26j0cfry2wrpvb7r0000gn/T/pip-install-y3izz7rd/xmlsec_1b2a1e6a17e447509a7b6137df7d3b99/src/constants.c:304:46: note: expanded from macro 'PYXMLSEC_ADD_NS_CONSTANT'
tmp = PyUnicode_FromString((const char*)(JOIN(xmlSec, name))); 
^
/private/var/folders/0f/pwhvtlxn26j0cfry2wrpvb7r0000gn/T/pip-install-y3izz7rd/xmlsec_1b2a1e6a17e447509a7b6137df7d3b99/src/common.h:19:19: note: expanded from macro 'JOIN'
#define JOIN(X,Y) DO_JOIN1(X,Y)
^
/private/var/folders/0f/pwhvtlxn26j0cfry2wrpvb7r0000gn/T/pip-install-y3izz7rd/xmlsec_1b2a1e6a17e447509a7b6137df7d3b99/src/common.h:20:23: note: expanded from macro 'DO_JOIN1'
#define DO_JOIN1(X,Y) DO_JOIN2(X,Y)
^
/private/var/folders/0f/pwhvtlxn26j0cfry2wrpvb7r0000gn/T/pip-install-y3izz7rd/xmlsec_1b2a1e6a17e447509a7b6137df7d3b99/src/common.h:21:23: note: expanded from macro 'DO_JOIN2'
#define DO_JOIN2(X,Y) X##Y
^
:83:1: note: expanded from here
xmlSecSoap12Ns
^
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libxmlsec1/1.3.1_1/include/xmlsec1/xmlsec/strings.h:34:33: note: 'xmlSecXPath2Ns' declared here
XMLSEC_EXPORT_VAR const xmlChar xmlSecXPath2Ns[];
^
2 errors generated.
error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for xmlsec
Building wheel for django-rest-hooks (setup.py) ... done
Created wheel for django-rest-hooks: filename=django_rest_hooks-1.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl size=15090 sha256=8983847048fbae8c2d8deeb4660e83f296da791a25da1a2492bbb1ce37279edb
Stored in directory: /private/var/folders/0f/pwhvtlxn26j0cfry2wrpvb7r0000gn/T/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-30rug9ga/wheels/a9/c5/57/b2faf51aac09d7d971d9304b3bdce7ceeb90e7444de4ab28be
Successfully built django-rest-hooks
Failed to build xmlsec
ERROR: Could not build wheels for xmlsec, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
`

This is the error I am getting, I am using python3.8 and I am using macOs.

Actually I have tried to install this project on Ubuntu it gets install successfully but On MacOs It is throwing this kind of error. I have also installed these packages brew install libxml2 libxmlsec1 pkg-config.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to limit field access on a model based on user type on Graphene/Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49084322/how-to-limit-field-access-on-a-model-based-on-user-type-on-graphene-django)